# Scraping data from web page using Jsoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup, htmlunit

I am new to Jsoup and I need to scrape the data from below webpage.

Here is the link.

[Webpage](http://dtdc.in/tracking/tracking_results_api.asp?strCnno=V25575555&Ttype=awb_no)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with jsoup, but using [this online soup parser](https://try.jsoup.org/~LGB7rk_atM2roavV0d-czMt3J_g) I got some pretty good results with the query `#box-table-a tbody tr td` but it would need some refining and sorting.

The way I came to that query was by looking through the HTML code and identifying the div for each section, which has the id `box-table-a`, which all contain a tbody, tr, and td element.